# Using Javascript to return the selected text in the address bar in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, bookmarklet, address-bar

I'm trying to write a bookmarklet that will call `encodeURI` on the selected text in the address bar of Firefox.

I know about `document.location` but it doesn't quite cut it because I want the user to be able to select the text from the URL they wish to use not just all of the text, the domain name, the path, the port, or the anchor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cursor position in the URL bar is not scriptable.

Comment: Poo.  I was hoping that it was.  Oh well... thanks for the answer.